# How to show a property of the Natural Logarithm

Tags: integration, logarithms

Our professor gave us the definition of the natural logarithm: $\ln (x) =  \int_{t=1}^{t=x}\frac{1}{t}\,dt $

Furthermore, I am supposed to show that
$ \int_{t=0}^{t=x}\frac{1}{1-t}  \,dt = \ln{\frac{1}{1-x}} $ when $x<1$.

So what I did was substituting $t=1-u$ and $dt=-du$ which yields

$$ -\int_{t=0}^{t=x}\frac{1}{u}\,du $$

If I am not mistaken I would have to change the interval $(0,x)$ as well, right?
Using $u=1-t$ the new interval would be $(1,1-x)$.
This would give us the new integral:
$$ -\int_{u=1}^{u=1-x}\frac{1}{u}\,du $$

What is the next step now? Was my procedure correct (especially the step with changing the integral's interval). I am not very familiar with this.

Comment: Yes, you very much need to change to interval accordingly when making a substitution. Just look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Definite_integrals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mostly done, indeed by the given definition for $\ln x$ we have

$$-\int_{u=1}^{u=1-x}\frac{1}{u}\,du =-\ln(1-x)+\ln 1 =\ln \frac1{1-x}$$

Answer (score 3):

$\int_{0}^{x}\dfrac{1}{1-t}dt=\int_{0}^{x}\dfrac{1}{1-t}d(t-1)=-\int_{1}^{1-x}\dfrac{1}{u}du=-\ln(1-x)+\ln1=\ln\dfrac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: Typesetting tip:  `$\ln x$` produces $\ln x$, just as `$\log x$` produces $\log x$.